# AJAX call not firing from inside if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following code. There is a button in the UI that when clicked executes the `if` statement. I pass in a URL from a database and compare it to the current URL the user is on. If they match I want to run the code below, else I want to open the correct tab then run the code below.

With this code below I mean everything below starting from `$('#sceanrioDropdownList').change(function () {...}`. The code then checks a drop down and gets the selected Id from which an AJAX call is made to my web API that uses that Id in a stored procedure to return the results. The returned data is then iterated over and stored in variables which I am using to append to specific inputs, buttons and drop downs.

This is what I have so far and I think I have developed this correctly. The issue that I am currently having is that the UI wants everything from `...` to be run if the `if` statement is `true`. I have tried <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to copy the code into the `if` statement. I have also tried putting it in a new function and referencing that function n the `if` statement. Both do not work and I was using `console.log` to inspect the returned data.

It does however when I attempt to call it from inside i statement it doesn't return any data or error. It just doesn't seem to fire.

Is there a way in which I can achieve the functionality I desire? Do you have any suggestions as to if I have done something wrong. Thanks in advance.

```js
$('#automate').click(automateButton);

function automateButton() {
  if (webpageUrl == activeTabUrl) {
    // do nothing
  } else {
    // Window opens
    window.open(webpageUrl);
  }
}

$('#scenarioDropdownList').change(function() {
  var scenarioId = $('#scenarioDropdownList option:selected').prop('id');
  getData(scenarioId);
});

function getData(scenarioId) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'http://localhost:54442/api/scenariodatas/GetScenarioData',
    data: {
      scenarioId: scenarioId
    },
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: scenarioData,
    error: function() {
      console.log("There has been an error retrieving the data");
    }
  });
}

function scenarioData(response) {
  $.each(response, function(key, val) {
    var fieldType = val.fieldType;
    var fieldName = val.fieldName;
    var fieldValue = val.fieldValue;
    var field = $(fieldName);

    if (field != undefined) {
      switch (fieldType) {
        case "Input":
          $(field).val(fieldValue);
          break;
        case "Button":
          $(field).click();
          break;
        case "Select":
          $(field).val(fieldValue);
          break;
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

onChange don´t work well with buttons because onChange detect a change in the value of your component, because of this, it´s highly recommended to use onClick when you use a button.

```
$('#scenarioDropdownList').click(function() {
  var scenarioId = $('#scenarioDropdownList option:selected').prop('id');
  getData(scenarioId);
});
```

I recommend you to put alerts when you are trying to test this sort of JS 
EJM:

```
$('#scenarioDropdownList').change(function() {
alert('button active');
  var scenarioId = $('#scenarioDropdownList option:selected').prop('id');
  getData(scenarioId);
});
```

this alert allow you to know if the code is firing or not

Comment: I have altered the code thanks to your advice. Unfortunately the ajax call still does not fire.